# How to name the new columns when splitting by delimiter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe `df2`:

```
tree    cues    directions  thresholds  exits
1   1   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant    >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6   1;0;1;0.5
2   2   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI  >;>;>   126;29;29.7 0;1;0.5
3   3   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant    >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6   1;0;0;0.5
4   4   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant    >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6   1;1;0;0.5
5   5   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant    >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6   0;1;0;0.5
6   6   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI  >;>;>   126;29;29.7 0;0;0.5
7   7   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant    >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6   1;1;1;0.5
8   8   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant    >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6   0;0;0;0.5
```

and I want to split up ["cues", "exits", "directions", "thresholds"] into 4 columns each.

So, I did it like this:

```
df3 = df2['cues'].str.split(';',expand=True)
df4 = df2['directions'].str.split(';',expand=True)
df5 = df2['thresholds'].str.split(';',expand=True)
df6 = df2['exits'].str.split(';',expand=True)

# Concatinated these dataframes into one. 
df = pd.concat([df2, df3, df4, df5, df6], axis = 1)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# I drop the initial columns that I don't need anymore
df.drop(columns =['tree','cues', 'directions', 'thresholds', 'exits'], inplace = True) 

df

    0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3
0   PLC2hrOGTT  Age BMI TimesPregnant   >   >   >   >   126 29  29.7    6   1   0   1   0.5
1   PLC2hrOGTT  Age BMI None    >   >   >   None    126 29  29.7    None    0   1   0.5 None
2   PLC2hrOGTT  Age BMI TimesPregnant   >   >   >   >   126 29  29.7    6   1   0   0   0.5
3   PLC2hrOGTT  Age BMI TimesPregnant   >   >   >   >   126 29  29.7    6   1   1   0   0.5
4   PLC2hrOGTT  Age BMI TimesPregnant   >   >   >   >   126 29  29.7    6   0   1   0   0.5
5   PLC2hrOGTT  Age BMI None    >   >   >   None    126 29  29.7    None    0   0   0.5 None
6   PLC2hrOGTT  Age BMI TimesPregnant   >   >   >   >   126 29  29.7    6   1   1   1   0.5
7   PLC2hrOGTT  Age BMI TimesPregnant   >   >   >   >   126 29  29.7    6   0   0   0   0.5
```

as you can see now I am left with DataFrame columns which are not unique. Therefore, I wanted to ask how can I give a name to columns when I split so that I have unique columns at the end when I concatenate them into one dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
df3 = df2['cues'].str.split(';',expand=True)
```

try

```
df2[['cues1','cues2','cues3','cues4']] = df2['cues'].str.split(';',expand=True)
df2 = df2.drop('cues', 1)
```

follow the same approach for others. If you want to have a copy of original DataFrame, use `df2_cp = df2.copy()`.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'`

Comment: alright it worked. Thanks! But is there a way to not write cue1, cue2, cue3, cue4, because sometimes it might have 3 cues and sometimes 4, it depends on the dataset and the trees that are generated. Can we make that dynamic?

Comment: You may need something like this: `df3 = pandas.DataFrame(df2.cues.values.tolist(), df2.index).add_prefix('cues_')`

Comment: where should I write this? can you edit your question?